# Given an array of `first n` natural numbers with one element missing and one duplicate element. Figure out both numbers

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, numbers, sequence

Given an array of `first n` natural numbers with one element missing and one duplicate element. figure out both numbers. I was asked this question in one of the interviews.

For example, the sample array is

```
5, 2, 1, 4, 5
where n=5
```

Answer for the given array should be:

```
missing element = 3
duplicate element = 5
```

Is it possible to come-up with the solution without iterating the array.

I was able to come-up with a solution having complexity O(nlogn), without extra space. Does any O(n) solution exist (without extra space)?

Comment: What do you mean with "without iterating the array"? You mean without checking all of them or without going multiple times through the array?

Comment: Please read the updated problem definition.

Comment: The power of google:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-a-repeating-and-a-missing-number/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say that you have numbers `1,...,n`. Now, denote their sum `1 + 2 + ... + n` as `S`. If we denote the missing number as `j` and the duplicit one as `k`, we will get for the modified sum `S' = S - j + k`, so that's one equation for two variables. We can repeat the same procedure, but this time, summing second powers, thus `S_2 = 1 + 4 + ... + n^2`. For the sequence with one missing and one duplicit number, the result will be `S_2' = S_2 - j*j + k*k`. Thus we get two equations for two variables.

In total, we have:

```
S'   = S   - j   + k
S_2' = S_2 - j*j + k*k
```

therefore

```
k - j     = S'   - S   =: a
k*k - j*j = S_2' - S_2 =: b
```

where we introduced the symbols `a` and `b` to simplify the notation.
Now, `k*k - j*j = (k - j)*(k + j)`, thus:

```
k - j     = a
k*k - j*j = a * (k + j) = b
```

summing both equations gives:

```
2*k = b/a + a
2*j = b/a - a
```

For your particular example:

```
S   = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4  + 5  = 15
S_2 = 1 + 4 + 9 + 16 + 25 = 55
```

For the series with one missing and one duplicit element:

```
S'   = 5  + 2 + 1 + 4  + 5  = 17
S_2' = 25 + 4 + 1 + 16 + 25 = 71
```

then:

```
a = S'   - S   = 2
b = S_2' - S_2 = 16
```

therefore:

```
2*k = 8 + 2 = 10
2*j = 8 - 2 = 6
```

which gives:

```
k = 5, j = 3
```

In practice (as noted by @HermanTheGermanHesse), one can obtain closed-form [expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) for `S` as well as `S_2` in terms of polynomials in `n` (so-called Faulhaber's formulae), namely: `S = n*(n+1)/2` and `S_2 = n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)/6`. Therefore it is just sufficient to go once over the input data, accumulate `S'` and `S_2'`, and use the formulae for `k` and `j` given above...

Comment: From [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/sum-of-n-n2-or-n3/):  
S = (n(n+1))/2  
S_2 = (n(n+1)(2n+1))/6  
So you don't have to calculatete it step by step ;)

Comment: @HermanTheGermanHesse indeed, that should simplify things! :) I will include it into the answer...